# Make class thread safe in Java if used by multiple classes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

This question was asked to me in interview . My answer was

1. One of the way is using Singleton with double locked checking with synchronization .
2. Using Volatile keyword as it will load the data directly into memory instead of caching it .

He was not satisfied with the answer and was telling me this is not a right way .

Can Someone please help with answers with example that would help